# How can I become thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm looking at an application where I'm going to handle several integrations and need them to run in threads. I need the threads to "report back to the mothership (aka the main-loop)". The snippet:

```
class App
{
    public delegate void StopHandler();
    public event StopHandler OnStop;

    private bool keepAlive = true;

    public App()
    {
        OnStop += (() => { keepAlive = false; });

        new Thread(() => CheckForStop()).Start();
        new Thread(() => Update()).Start();

        while (keepAlive) { }
    }

    private void CheckForStop()
    {
        while (keepAlive) if (Console.ReadKey().Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.Enter)) OnStop();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        int counter = 0;

        while (keepAlive)
        {
            counter++;

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] Update #{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), counter));

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is variable `keepAlive`. By its use its not thread safe. My question is how can I make it thread safe.

Would it become safe(r) if `Update` used `while(true)` instead of `keepAlive` and event `OnStop` aborted the thread?

Comment: A bool is not a synchronization object, AutoResetEvent is.  .NET has handy thread wrappers that help you leverage CancellationToken.  Do step back and wonder how that thread is useful, spinning endlessly in that while loop and burning 100% core doing nothing useful.  It might as well call Update().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object and [lock it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

```
class App
{
    public delegate void StopHandler();
    public event StopHandler OnStop;
    private object keepAliveLock = new object();
    private bool keepAlive = true;

....
    private void Update()
    {
        int counter = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            lock(keepAliveLock)
            {
                 if(!keepAlive) 
                      break;
            }
            counter++;

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] Update #{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), counter));

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, that every access to keepAlive needs to be locked (surround by lock statement). Take care of deadlock situations.

Comment: thank you for your input. I dont know much about lock, but by locking it in a thread, i need to test the lock in another (if available)?

Comment: You can follow the link behind lock it word for detailed explanation. lock is very simple, you do not need to check additional Monitor or anything else, also you could. But if the object is locked, lock will wait until the lock is released. If it is not locked, it will get locked by lock. Due to this behavior you need to take care of deadlock situations.

Comment: Note: Using a lock for each access to a variable is likely to degrade performance. I think @MichaelRandall gave a better solution to ensure your bool is thread-safe. However. check my answer for a nicer solution.

Comment: volatile does not make a bool threadsafe when writing. If lock degrades performance depends on the number of lock situation happening. Naturally your solution is also nice and a bit cleaner from point of reading the code. But for small situations I always prefer lock due to less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the specific wording of your question and your example code (in regards to `keepAlive`) simply use `volatile` (for simple *Read Access* to `bool`). As to if there are other ways to better your code, this is another story.

```
private volatile bool keepAlive = true;
```

For *Simple Types* and access such as `bool`, then `volatile` is sufficient - this ensures that threads don't cache the value.

Read and writes to `bool` are *Atomic* as found in [C# Language Spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278(VS.71).aspx).

> Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char,
>   byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and reference types.

**Furthermore**

> Partition I, Section 12.6.6 of the CLI spec states: "A conforming CLI
>   shall guarantee that read and write access to properly aligned memory
>   locations no larger than the native word size is atomic when all the
>   write accesses to a location are the same size.

Its also worth looking up [volatile (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile)

> The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by
>   multiple threads that are executing at the same time. Fields that are
>   declared volatile are not subject to compiler optimizations that
>   assume access by a single thread. This ensures that the most
>   up-to-date value is present in the field at all times.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally change this from waiting for a bool to become false to use the ManualResetEvent. Also use a System.Timers.Timer for the update rather than a loop:

```
private ManualResetEvent WaitForExit;
private ManualResetEvent WaitForStop;

public App()
{
    WaitForExit = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    WaitForStop = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    new Thread(() => CheckForStop()).Start();
    new Thread(() => Update()).Start();

    WaitForExit.WaitOne();
}

private void CheckForStop()
{
    while (true) 
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.Enter)) 
        {
            WaitForStop.Set();
            break;
        }
}

private void Update()
{
    int counter = 0;

    Timer timer = new Timer(3000);
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Start();

    WaitForStop.WaitOne();

    timer.Stop();

    WaitForExit.Set();
}

private int counter = 1;
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] Update #{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), counter++));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed yourself, it is the mutable `keepAlive` variable that you share between threads that causes your headache. My suggestion is to remove it. More generally:

## Stop sharing mutable state between threads

Basically all multi-threading problems come from threads sharing mutable state.

Make `keepAlive` a private instance variable on the object that does the printing. Let that class instantiate it's own thread, and let all messages sent to the object be placed on a ConcurrentQueue:

```
class Updater
{
    // All messages sent to this object are stored in this concurrent queue
    private ConcurrentQueue<Action> _Actions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    private Task _Task;
    private bool _Running;
    private int _Counter = 0;

    // This is the constructor. It initializes the first element in the action queue,
    // and then starts the thread via the private Run method:
    public Updater()
    {
        _Running = true;
        _Actions.Enqueue(Print);
        Run();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        _Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // The while loop below quits when the private _Running flag
            // or if the queue of actions runs out.
            Action action;
            while (_Running && _Actions.TryDequeue(out action))
            {
                action();
            }
        });
    }

    // Stop places an action on the event queue, so that when the Updater
    // gets to this action, the private flag is set.
    public void Stop()
    {
        _Actions.Enqueue(() => _Running = false);
    }

    // You can wait for the actor to exit gracefully...
    public void Wait()
    {
        if (_Running)
            _Task.Wait();
    }

    // Here's where the printing will happen. Notice that this method
    // puts itself unto the queue after the Sleep method returns.
    private void Print()
    {
        _Counter++;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] Update #{1}",
            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), _Counter));

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Enqueue a new Print action so that the thread doesn't terminate
        if (_Running)
            _Actions.Enqueue(Print);
    }
}
```

## Now we just need a way to stop the thread:

```
class Stopper
{
    private readonly Updater _Updater;
    private Task _Task;

    public Stopper(Updater updater)
    {
        _Updater = updater;
        Run();
    }

    // Here's where we start yet another thread to listen to the console:
    private void Run()
    {
        // Start a new thread
        _Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (Console.ReadKey().Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.Enter))
                {
                    _Updater.Stop();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // This is the only public method!
    // It waits for the user to press enter in the console.
    public void Wait()
    {
        _Task.Wait();
    }
}
```

## Gluing it all together

All we really need now is a `main` method:

```
class App
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Instantiate actors
        Updater updater = new Updater();
        Stopper stopper = new Stopper(updater);

        // Wait for the actors to expire
        updater.Wait();
        stopper.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Graceful exit");
    }
}
```

## Further reading:

The above method for encapsulating mutable state for a thread is called the [Actor Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model).

The premise is, that all threads are encapsulated by their own class, and only that class can interact with the thread. In the example above, this is done by placing `Action`s on a concurrent queue and then just executing it one by one.